# How about instead of 'This question already has an answer here', use 'This question already had an answer here'?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, hyperlinks, deleted-questions

I was regularly enjoying my day when I came across a nice ordinary-looking question, so I read it!

[image: Question I read]

You see that nice-looking hyperlink?  Good, because I see it, too.  And what happens when I, say, click on it?  **Guess Again!**

[image: 404 Question I was taken to]

Mmm, waffles....

Was I being trolled?  I went through all the work of pressing that nice-looking hyperlink for a question I was hoping to read, and I get taken to a 404 page!  Can SO/Meta SO at least say [deleted] after [closed], etc, or change `This question already has an answer here` to `This question already had an answer here?`  I wasted so much time clicking that link when I could've read something that wouldn't make me waste my time!  This is an outrage!

**Edit** Another question hangs in the balance of the universe.  Will Jeff kill me? https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105

Comment: Actually does it really make any sense to leave it closed as duplicate if the duplicate doesn't exist?

Comment: @MartinSmith I don't think it was a duplicate, it just had an answer at that non-duplicate

Comment: It was a duplicate. Says so in the question title.

Comment: @MartinSmith Oh, yeah... well, if it is a duplicate, then that means it should be closed and deleted as that other question was, I guess

Comment: Well if the question was already asked twice why delete them? Probably it will just be asked again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to me that the best way to handle this situation would be to automatically reopen the closed [duplicate] when the master post is deleted.

This should not be done instantly as that could make maintenance tasks difficult, but periodically the engine could scan through and reopen so-called duplicates that no longer have a (non-deleted) master.

Comment: If a moderator deletes the master post, shouldn't the duplicate same be deleted?

Comment: The dupe shouldn't be automatically deleted, @ManofSnow. Dupes are rarely *exact* dupes, and the duplicate might have some redeeming features.

Comment: And probably it should be automatically bumped by community after reopen-ing to give people a chance to review it / supply an answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Suggestion B: Disallow deletion

Questions which are dupe targets should be protected from deletion. You should not be permitted to delete such questions till you have dealt with all the dangling pointers their removal would leave behind.

[See also Suggestion A: Autoflag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/218314/147191).

Answer (score 0):

### Suggestion A: Autoflag

When I find a question closed as a dupe of a deleted question, I always give it a custom flag, as follows:

> This question has been closed as a duplicate of a deleted question. It should (a) be reopened, (b) be closed for some other reason, or (c) be deleted itself.

I may then add a recommendation, depending on the situation. Perhaps the system could raise such mod flags in future? Surely questions which are dupe targets aren't deleted so often that this would be an undue burden on the mods.

[See also Suggestion B: Disallow deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/218316/147191).

Comment: I much prefer the autoflag to auto reopening, but the problem is the moderator who handles the flag may not be qualified to answer the question about how it should be closed.  If we can figure a way to get this into the community's hands, that would be ideal